# Find the sum of two double integrals that have no primitive

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Given
$$\int _0^1\left(\int _e^5\frac{dx}{x^2\ln\left(x\right)}\:\right)dy+\int _1^{\ln\left(5\right)}\:\left(\int _{e^y}^5\frac{dx}{x^2\ln\left(x\right)}\:\right)dy$$
Find the sum of the integrals

I'm completely clueless on how I can find the answer here, I do think the integrals don't have a primitive but how can I find the sum here?

Answer (score 2):

The first term is just $$\int _{e}^5\frac{1}{x^2\ln x}dx$$

The second term is

$$\int_1^{\ln 5}\int _{e^y}^5\frac{1}{x^2\ln x}dxdy$$

$$=\int_e^{ 5}\int _{1}^{\ln x}\frac{dx}{x^2\ln x}dydx$$

by change of order.

Can you finish it?

Comment: Ah.. didn't think of that, thank you very much now I can solve it.

Comment: @Savantik Wonderful!